# Why does the explorer window in Windows 7 jump to the selected folder when I don't want it to?

Tags: windows-7

I've just moved from Windows XP to 7, and 7 seems to have this bizarre bug in Explorer (the one for files, not Internet Explorer). When I'm opening folders in the left-hand pane without selecting them, if I wait for about 3 seconds before opening the next one, the view will jump to display the folder I have selected, rather than the series of folders I'm opening. It's quite frustrating when I open a folder, search around for the sub-folder I want, only to have to drag the view back down from what is usually the OS drive. This happens on both my home and work computers. Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Edit: I have just noticed that, at least on my work computer, when it does this, it also opens/finds the other computers on the network, which refreshes the pane, which is what resets the scroll to the selected folder. This usually happens a few seconds after the window is opened, and not at any other time. It also mostly happens on Open/Save dialogues, not Explorer so much. Still no closer to fixing the issue, though.

Comment: This is not the default behavior.  What third party shell extensions do you have installed? ie Teracopy

Comment: Search and folder options , General "Show all folders" and "Automatically expand folders" Are the only things I can think of. I messed with them a couple of times and cant really figure out what they do yet ?? but they are there :-) I messed with trying to use the navigation pain for drag&drop , and got ticked off at it again (doesn't last long) and went back to Q-Dir a quad window explorer I like.

Comment: Can you include screenshots

Answer (score 1):

Window forum gives a helpful answer. Resetting the folder options did the trick for me. 
the forums detailed answer is at: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/windows-explorer-moves-the-selected-folder-to/78c18738-2818-43f7-8ca2-b3322cd8ff0d?auth=1 
Good Luck

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: That's a very long thread with numerous responses and it isn't clear which one you're referring to.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

edit: 2012-02-24: actually I was talking about a similar but slightly different bug.

This has been a [known bug](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproperf/thread/17a83954-8c3c-4d45-9dd6-03f6cdd1604c/) for three years. It seems like Microsoft simply do not want to fix it but lock it away...  it is such a PITA I just don't get it why they wouldn't fix it.

Comment: This is definitely bizarre, but it's not exactly the bug I mean. My side pane moves at times when I don't click. Also, I don't double-click on folders, I expand them with the arrow, leaving the root still selected. Strangely, when you expand folders the way I do, you don't get the bug you describe.

Comment: oops, you are right. my link describes a different bug. I have them both.... :|   driving me nuts

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have the "select on hover" setting enabled, but I couldn't tell
you where that option is located.

Comment: Certainly not this. I would definitely notice if that was the case. It jumps to the folder already selected, regardless of whether it's in the view or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "Edit" part of you question gives a clue to the answer. The Network branch is expanding a few seconds after everything else and is causing the jump. If you keep it expanded, it will continue to cause the explorer to jump in that application and in others. But if you hit the - sign next to the network icon to shrink it, it will stay unexpanded on future opens and saves and won't cause the jump (or so I hope).